# nodejs / mongoDb: update many fields in one request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-redux

how can I update many orderStatus instead of only one?

`request.body.type` is by default string and contains only one type;

and when `isCompleted` for the type go true I want even for previous enum index `isCompleted` go true

is it possible or do I need to modify it in the front-end?

here is the code

```js
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    orderStatus: [
      {
        type: {
          type: String,
          enum: ["ordered", "packed", "shipped", "delivered"],
          default: "ordered",
        },
        date: {
          type: Date,
        },
        isCompleted: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

```js
exports.updateOrder = (req, res) => {
  Order.updateOne(
    { _id: req.body.orderId, "orderStatus.type": req.body.type },
    {
      $set: {
        "orderStatus.$": [
          { type: req.body.type, date: new Date(), isCompleted: true },
        ],
      },
    }
  ).exec((error, order) => {
```

Comment: Have you tried array filters with the update?

Comment: where can i put array filter inside updateOrder ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use updateMany() operation

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   <query>,
   { $set: { status: "D" }, $inc: { quantity: 2 } },
   ...
)
```